# Can't create DCOS cluster with m3.medium

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, mesosphere, dcos

I have an error with the DC/OS cloudformation template.

> Your requested instance type (m3.medium) is not supported in your requested Availability Zone (us-east-1d)

I also read that m3 are being deprecated by aws.

How can I change the instance of the machines in the cloudformation script?

Comment: See my answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808810/cloudformation-template-gives-non-windows-instances-with-a-virtualization-type. Download the template and add instance type parameter.

Comment: thanks that helps, I also change the ami to ami-1ad0000c because the other use paravirtualization and no HVM

Comment: Upvote my answer if it helped you :)